# URL base no coincide con ruta principal Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Estoy utilizando un directorio extra dentro de public_html, ahí tengo mi código hecho con Laravel.

Ejemplo: public_html/nuevo_directorio

El problema es que al intentar entrar al sitio https://mi_dominio.com no entra al index a no ser que ingrese a https://mi_dominio.com/nuevo_directorio, entonces quisiera saber cómo configurar HTACCESS o Laravel para que mi dominio por sí solo apunte directamente al index que está dentro de dicho directorio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes crear un archivo `.htaccess` en la raíz de la carpeta `public_html` para cambiar la raíz de tu servidor haciendo una redirección pero que no sea una `302`, el archivo en el interior tendrá lo siguiente:

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mi_dominio.com$ [NC,OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !nuevo_directorio/
RewriteRule (.*) /nuevo_directorio/$1 [L]
```

Debes colocar tu dominio en `mi_dominio.com` y el directorio al que quieres redireccionar en `nuevo_directorio`

Comment: Me funcionó!!!!, muchas gracias :) te daría puntuación, pero mi reputación aún no me lo permite :(

Comment: De nada :) no te preocupes @Hadad